# Is there an add-on for batch STL importing?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, import

I've been able to track down add-ons for batch Obj import and batch STL export but I can't find one for batch STL import. Does anyone have a link to such an addon or have a python script?

Answer (score 1):

Start with importing obj file:`bpy.ops.import_scene.obj`

Then you export the scene with `bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl` : [doc](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.export_mesh.html#bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl)

After doing this, you need to delete all instance inside your scene and loop the process again. Should be a fairly easy add-on without tricky point.